# Kubernetes & Docker Efficiency

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I've been looking for information on how efficiently Kubernetes & Docker are in terms of using machine resources, but I haven't found much so far. Here are my three questions, all about Kubernetes+Docker:

- If multiple containers on the same node are running the same binary, are the code pages shared between all these instances? That is, is there a single set of physical pages allocated on the node for all these processes? For example, if I'm running a service mesh like Istio, which runs Envoy in every pod, is the system smart enough to only load the Envoy code in memory once, or does all the indirection taking place prevent the Linux kernel from recognizing that sharing is possible?
- In a large Kubernetes deployment, there will end up being a considerable number of redundantly downloaded docker images on each node. Instead, it would seem more effective to have a single in-cluster repository for these images that all nodes can fetch from. I saw [this](https://docs.docker.com/ee/dtr/admin/configure/external-storage/nfs/) about having docker use NFS for a common image store. Is this the only answer?
- I heard there's a practical limit to the number of pods Kubernetes will schedule on a single node (30). Such a small limit forces you to use smaller VMs in order to be able to fully saturate them. Anybody know why this limit exists and whether it will eventually be raised? I ask this in the context of trying to run Kubernetes on bare metal where VMs aren't used at all. In such a world, I'd want to be able to pack way more than 30 pods on a (large) physical machine.

Thank you for any insights or pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You state your question in the way that you plan to use docker as container runtime for kubernetes. That is fine - but there are more choices. Depending on the runtime the answers will change.
In general kubernetes provides an abstraction over the actual scheduling and running of pods/containers. Perhaps you invest too much human time into details that can be solved with more metal, which is cheap.

Multiple containers on a single node are usually (docker/containerd/crio) just system processes. Like you launch your Apache httpd multiple times yourself. If the kernel uses memory deduplication, it can indeed share pages.
If you use a container runtime that launches micro-VMs (firecracker,kata, ...) I doubt memory deduplication will be possible.

I would not recommend to share storage for the container images, f.e. with NFS. With some customer setups I had to diagnose issues caused by this. like deadlocks. Basically you would reduce the robustness of your cluster in order to save disk space. Just use more metal.

The usual limit is 110 Pods per node which is usually plenty. You can change this limit using `--max-pods` parameter to the kubelet process or configuration file for kubelet. The reason for the limit is that the management of a pod incurs effort on the kubelet and etcd/apiserver side.

Comment: Using "more metal" is a viable option for small deployments. At scale, "more metal" can actually mean dozens of millions of dollars annually. When managing large deployments, what seems like small optimizations can have a significant impact on the bottom line and the total opex of a product.

Comment: The Kubernetes website states a maximum of 5000 nodes in a cluster, max of 150,000 pods and 300,000 containers, and 100 pods per node. At full capacity that means  an average of 30 pods per node. And 100 pods per node is really not much for hardware with dozens/hundreds of cores for example. Seems k8s needs some scale work.

Comment: The limits have different reasons and if you take them all together you reach a scaling limit for a single cluster, right. If you reach that limit and want to operate just  a single cluster you might need to look at alternatives since kubernetes is not the right fit for your use case, indeed.